# Extract domain name from affiliate URL using PHP

Tags: php

Here is the format of affiliate URL I have `http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2119&&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netmeds.com%2F%3Fsource_attribution%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_source%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_medium%3DCPS-Emails%26utm_campaign%3DEmails`

If you see it has 2 URLs:
first URL: is for vcommission.com and 
Second URL: netmeds.com

I have CSV file with lot of rows. Each rows may have different second URL. I wanted to get second URL for each rows. First URL is also not static as for different CSV, this would also different.

How can I get second URL?

Answer (score 1):

Some basic string parsing like this should give you an idea.

```
$url='http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2119&&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netmeds.com%2F%3Fsource_attribution%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_source%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_medium%3DCPS-Emails%26utm_campaign%3DEmails';

list($u,$q)=explode('url=',urldecode($url));
$o=(object)parse_url($q);

echo $o->host;
```

Comment: Perfect, I tried this and it's working.. Thank You :)

Comment: Perfect, I tried this and it's working.. Thank You :)

Answer (score 0):

A good way to find the domain for a URL is with parse_url

Unfortunately due to the way your data is stored this is not really an option however you may be able to use some sort of regex to find contained web addresses in the query string

```
<?php
$url = "http://tracking.vcommission.com/aff_c?offer_id=2119&&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.netmeds.com%2F%3Fsource_attribution%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_source%3DVC-CPS-Emails%26utm_medium%3DCPS-Emails%26utm_campaign%3DEmails";
$p = parse_url($url);
$pattern = "/www[^%]*/";

preg_match($pattern, $p['query'], $result);

var_dump($result);
```

You may need to adjust the regex pattern based on how the other data presents itself.